# Training Data for Secondary Protein Structure prediction using neural network

Tags: bioinformatics, artificial-neural-network

I am trying to find some training dataset for prediction of Secondary Structure of Protein. I am having problems finding them online.

Answer (score 2):

The standard benchmark dataset is the one from Lindahl, which consists of 976 × 975 target-template protein pairs.

> Lindahl, E. & Elofsson, A. [Identification of related proteins on family, superfamily and fold level.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10623551) Journal of molecular biology 295, 613–625 (2000).

It is for example used in the following articles:

- [Improving Protein Fold Recognition by Deep Learning Networks](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep17573)
- [Improving protein fold recognition by random forest](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4251042/)

Another resource is [SCOP: Structural Classification of Proteins](http://scop.mrc-lmb.cam.ac.uk/scop/).

> Nearly all proteins have structural similarities with other proteins and, in some of these cases, share a common evolutionary origin. The SCOP database, created by manual inspection and abetted by a battery of automated methods, aims to provide a detailed and comprehensive description of the structural and evolutionary relationships between all proteins whose structure is known. As such, it provides a broad survey of all known protein folds, detailed information about the close relatives of any particular protein, and a framework for future research and classification.